# 'Method' is used like a 'type' error C#

Tags: c#

So I have this bit of code, that for some reason won't compile, because it says I am using a method as a type....
I for some odd reason can't see what it is that is supposed to be wrong, the only article google gave me, was an article here that is less than useless.

So my question is, what is wrong with this code:

```
static void Main() {
    Application.Run(new stat_checker());
}
public stat_checker() {
}
```

Comment: `public stat_checker()`, is that in `class stat_checker` or (assuming) `class Program`? If the latter, you are missing a return type but I doubt this is the case since you are calling `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Application.Run();` function takes a form as its argument for example:
`Application.Run(new Form1());`

Answer (score 10):

Well, you're calling `new` on it, so it looks like you want to declare a *type* called `stat_checker`:

```
public class stat_checker : Form
{
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to *call* `stat_checker` you'd need to write:

```
Application.Run(stat_checker());
```

But you *also* need to change `stat_checker` to be a valid type:

```
public Form stat_checker() {
    // Return something here
}
```

Were you trying to include this code *within* a type called `stat_checker`? If so, it should already work:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class stat_checker : Form {

    static void Main() {
        Application.Run(new stat_checker());
    }
    public stat_checker() {
    }
}
```

If you could tell us which of these scenarios you're actually trying to achieve, that would help. I'd also suggest that you start following .NET naming conventions, e.g. using `StatChecker` instead of `stat_checker`.

Comment: @Kris: "this." isn't part of any DLL. It's part of the language. I *strongly* suggest you learn the language from scratch with the aid of a book - ideally *not* with a GUI to start with. GUIs are hard enough to write even when you *do* know the language, let alone when you're struggling with syntax. Console apps are *much* simpler in that respect. I would recommend Essential C# 4 or C# 4 in a Nutshell.

Comment: @Kris: Yes, but "this." is just a way of representing a reference to the "current" object. It's not in a DLL at all.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a return type in your method definition:

```
public ??? stat_checker() {

}
```

Without a return type this is considered to be a constructor of the `stat_checker` type. So if you intended this to be a constructor it has to be put in a class called `stat_checker`.

Comment: Als it needs to be a constructor for a class that inherits ApplicationContext. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your intent, you need to do one of two things.

Either declare `stat_checker` as a class that is a `Form`,

```
static void Main() {
    Application.Run(new stat_checker());
}

public class stat_checker : Form {
// TODO: Implement the class
}
```

Or declare `stat_checker` as a method that returns a `Form` and remove the `new`,

```
static void Main() {
    Application.Run(stat_checker());
}
public Form stat_checker() { 
// TODO: Code that creates and returns a Form.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, **stat_checker** is declared as a method; the **new** keyword is used to create an instance of a type (class, etc) - the two don't mix.

If stat_check is a method, then lose the **Application.Run(new ...)** and just call it directly.

Is this a console application?  More details of what you're trying to accomplish would help us advise you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `stat_checked` is a function, not a class constructor for an ApplicationContext class, like it needs to be.

What you should do is something more like this:

```
class StatChecker : ApplicationContext
{
    public StatChecker()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

Then you can instantiate it like this:

```
Application.Run(new StatChecker());
```

Note that your StatChecker class has to extent or return ApplicationContext. The typical "Form" class, for instance, extends ApplicationContext which is why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as mismatched Namespaces They would need to be the same in both classes to use the unqualified new stat_checker(). This bit me once which is how I got here... ;-)